# Java UI program randomly freezes

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jbutton, freeze

I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer working on a basic array generating/searching program for homework.  I've got it working perfectly, but it will randomly freeze up (without throwing any exceptions or error messages that I can detect) after I set the search key.  The real problem, though, is that I can't always reproduce the error by doing the same thing.  I'm programming and running the program in Eclipse.

Here is the basic structure of my program; for simplicity's sake, I'm only including the actual code for the setter and button that seems to be causing the problem.  I suspect it's something simple, but I see no reason that this code should be locking up a program.

```
public class ArraySearcher extends JPanel
                       implements ActionListener  {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 6449138670325520140L;

/**
 * A program description.
 */


// Fields (array and search parameters)
static int key;
static int arraySize;
static int min;
static int max;
static int midpoint;
// (Number of search steps taken by each search algorithm)
static int linSteps;
static int binSteps;
// (JButtons, JLabels, JTextFields, and the log for displaying results)
static JButton runButton, chKeyButton, newArrayButton, exitButton;
static JTextField lStepField, bStepField;
static JTextField keyField;
static JTextField arraySizeField;
static JTextField time;
static JTextArea log;
// (The arrays to be used)
static int[] randArray, sortArray;
// (Makes the output formatting a little easier to read)
public static String newline = "\n", twolines = "\n\n";


// The constructor
public ArraySearcher() {

// Setting up the fields and GUI
    }


// Getters and setters
protected static int getKey() {
    return key;
}


protected static void setKey() {
    boolean success = false;
    // loop and try catch block to deal with the potential parsing exception
    while (success == false) {
        try {
            key = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Please enter the number you\nwish to search for:"));
            keyField.setText(Integer.toString(getKey()));
            success = true;
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "There was a number format error.  Please\n" +
                    "input only positive, whole numbers.");
        }
    }
}

    // More getters and setters...


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Implement the GUI, all other work is handled from
    // there and from within the constructor
    theGUI();
}


private static void theGUI() {
// Set up the GUI and allow user to set min and
// max values for the random number generator

    }


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Handling of the run/restart button.
    if (e.getSource() == runButton) {
    }

    // Handling the Change Key button
    else if (e.getSource() == chKeyButton) {
        setKey();
        chKeyButton.setText("Change Key");
        linSearch(getRandArray());          // Implicit searches triggered by
        binSearch(getRandArray());          // selecting a new search key
    }

    // Handling the New Array button
    else if (e.getSource() == newArrayButton) {
    }

    // Handling of the exit button.
    else if (e.getSource() == exitButton) {
    }
}


// Method for building the array of random numbers; includes an implicit search
// which can be canceled (i.e. just build and return the array) by passing it
// a false condition when it's called
private void arrayBuilder(boolean fullRun) {

}


private void linSearch(int[] arrayIn) {
    // Linear search method

}


private void binSearch(int[] arrayIn) {
    // Binary search method
    int result = -1;            // Location of a positive match; initialized to an impossible result
    int tempMax = arraySize;    // Dynamic maximum index for progressive midpoint calculations
    int tempMin = 0;            // Dynamic minimum index
    int newMid = 0;             // Dynamic midpoint
    int count = 0;              // Counts the steps required to find value
    boolean success = false;    // A loop escape boolean

    log.append("RUNNING BINARY SEARCH" + newline);      
    log.append("SORTING ARRAY..." + twolines);

    sortArray = sort(arrayIn);              // Sort the array prior to searching

    // Array midpoint index calculation
    midpoint = tempMax/2 - tempMin/2;   // Calculation prevents buffer overflow; allows for nonzero minimum
    newMid = midpoint;

    // Search loop
    while (tempMin != tempMax && success == false) {
        if (sortArray[newMid] == key) {
            success = true;
            result = newMid;
            count++;
        }

        else if (sortArray[newMid] < key) {
            tempMin = newMid;
            newMid = tempMax/2 - tempMin/2;
            count++;
        }

        else if (sortArray[newMid] > key) {
            tempMax = newMid;
            newMid = tempMax/2 - tempMin/2;
            count++;
        }
    }
    binSteps = count;
    bStepField.setText(Integer.toString(binSteps));
    log.append(twolines);

    if (result != -1) {
        log.append("Success!  The number " + Integer.toString(key) + " was found " +
                "at array location " + result + "." + newline);
    }
    else if (result == -1) {
        log.append("Failure.  The number " + Integer.toString(key) + 
                " was not found in the array." + newline);
    }

    log.append("The binary search was completed in " + Integer.toString(binSteps) + 
            " steps." + newline + newline);
    log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

}


private int[] sort(int[] arrayIn) {
    // Method for sorting the random array before
    // performing a binary search
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? That might help where you are getting problem.

Comment: Ugh, please remove the excessive use of statics in your code. And remember that any Swing GUI program is essentially multithreaded. Sounds like you are running into a deadlock issue.

Comment: If you debug or add a `println()`, can you tell if `setKey()` is returning? If so, maybe your search methods hang for some keys.

Comment: [The homework tag is obsolete now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @Perception: Swing programs are *not* multithreaded - there is a single Event Dispatch Thread that everything runs on.

Comment: @Russel: To my knowledge there are no other threads in use.  I honestly am nowhere near multiple thread level of programming skill.

Comment: @RussellZahniser: I thought my keyfield update would work the same as a println().  It updates a visible field in the GUI with the new search key.  It does not update when there is a freeze, however when I added a println() after the keyfield update but before setting success = true, I saw that it was updating the key and printing it to the console.

Comment: @pst, russelzahniser - the EDT is a separate thread from the main thread of the program. EDT + main thread = multithreading. A swing program will actually normally have more than these two threads, which you can verify yourself by running a simple one. And this is assuming you don't manually start any threads of your own.

Comment: @Troy D, every Java program is multithreaded. At the very least, main() is not run on the EDT.

Comment: @pst - I'm not sure what your point is then. It is impossible, with a standard JVM, to run a Swing program that is *not* multithreaded. I bring this point up not because the existence of a separate EDT thread is in itself important, but because the symptoms that the OP is running into seem highly indicative of a deadlock condition.

Comment: @Perception My point was "everything should be executing on the EDT already". However, I retracted all my comments as `theGUI` code is not posted. Thus, while I daresay it is an issue that should not be encountered in a trivial application that does not spawn new threads, I have no idea what said missing code is doing (and, perhaps he/she is indeed doing fun stuff off the EDT).

Comment: @Perception: Normally the main thread exists only long enough to start the EDT. The whole point of the EDT is that a correctly-written swing program is single-threaded except for background threads with very localized use.

Comment: @RussellZahniser - that is simply ... incorrect.

Comment: @RussellZahniser, Perception, pst:  Okay, so I've learned a lot.  First off, I learned how to use the debug function (hadn't been covered in any form at school).  YES, it's running four threads, according to debug.  But it's actually getting caught in a loop inside my binary search method, which I've added to the original post.  I think it's actually a problem with the search loop's logic.  Any input is welcome.

Comment: @Perception: All access to Swing components *must* be done on the EDT. See the [basic tutorial on Swing threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). There is a commonly-used loophole that allows the main thread to create components, provided that it does nothing more with those components as soon as any one of them has become visible. But for the main thread and the EDT to both be accessing components in your program is a programming error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `tempMax/2 - tempMin/2` will not get you the midpoint. Consider a simple example: if `tempMin = 2` and `tempMax = 5`, then `tempMax/2 - tempMin/2 = 5/2 - 2/2 = 2 - 1 = 1`.

The typical way to get the midpoint without overflow is `mid = (min + max) >>> 1`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when I started looking harder at the method.  I don't recognize the >>> symbol.  I tried to google it, but google disregards that symbol.  What does it do?

Comment: It's an unsigned right bitshift. See [this classic article](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) on how most Java binary search methods had an overflow bug in them that went unnoticed for years.

Comment: Outstanding.  This solved my problem.  Thanks for that article and the catch on my algorithm.  I also added in a +1 and -1 to the tempMin and tempMax recalculations to exclude the former midpoint.